# Tab host and fragments

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I working with a project In this project my requirements are based on tabs and fragments but im not getting how to deal with fragments in this..

My problem is..

```
1.In first screen I need to show three tabs at the bottom of the activity  
2.I thought to use tab activity but tab activity is deprecated  
3.So i decided to use tab host  
4.Until here it is fine i have used tab host and kept it at the bottom of the activity  
5.But When i have selected a tab it will show one fragment at the top of it    
6.And i kept a button in that fragment if i click on that it should navigate to another   fragment without the any changes in tabs.
7.here is my problem when i clicking im loosing tabs.
```

This is my problem
hope you guys have understood my problem
If you found any in convience in my question or if you feel it is lack of information please let me know that

Comment: actually im new to android so i think we can give more than one best answer so decided to pick two answers but when compared to two yours is best so i changed my vote

Comment: just wait up to your issue is solver after that we accepted which one best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have u see this

[THIS ONE](https://github.com/rameshkec85/BottomTabsFragmentTabHost)

and

[THIS ONE](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/)

Comment: thanq these examples are verry verry useful for meee thanq soo much